# MicroServices separate databased

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, cloud, microservices

I'm creating a micro services for example one for **user management** i.e (roles, credentials, rights, menus etc) related and one for bank account-details, now i have a scenario to getting user roles detail and rights detail from db, is it a good practice to repeat columns of database  **user management db**  i.e.(roles, rights) in **bank-account db**  as per requirement or duplicate data in **bank-account db** ?

Or no need to duplicate data in **bank-account db** and send a separate call to get user data first from **user management db** ?

please suggest a best possibility

Answer (score 0):

Waqas,

You're in microservices environment. There is a well-known Domain Driven Design (**DDD**) with one of a key pattern of [**Bounded Contexts**](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). That means you should try to avoid mixing the contexts and duplicate the user information in **bank-account db** (it might be inevitable some time, but I suppose not in your case).

Therefore, it's fine that you have to call **user management** service in order to gain the required information about your users.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Stepan Tsybulski. Also, I suggest you reduce the need for a bounded context to depend on the other to the minimum possible. So, duplication of data is the best option here. However, you do not have to have roles and rights in the Bank Account context / DB. I'd put in the Bank Account context only what's necessary in that context: User details (such as names, birthdates, etc.) + user id.

You get the roles and rights from the session. You manage roles in the User Management context only. It's good for security and consistency, plus it's the reason for using Contexts.

There are many ways to approach a problem, but that's how I'm doing it.